# How to re-attach kitchen cabinet laminate?

Tags: kitchens

In two different Formica-covered bottom cabinets in my house, the Formica is not perfectly attached to the wooden-base cabinets. The edges of the Formica have become unattached to the wooden cabinet. Our handyman re-glued the Formica in these two places, but the new glue did not stick. What can now be done to solve this problem of unattached Formica? These cabinets are 25 years old.

Answer (score 4):

Many years ago, I worked for Formica.  I can give the advice that worked at the time.

Firstly, try to remove the set glue if at all possible.  This is easier said than done if only the edges are unstuck.  You will have to get something flat between the laminate and the wood.

Secondly, use an epoxy-based glue, like Evo-stik or Bostick.  Not the sort where you have to mix two components and not wood glue.  Smear this under the edges, getting as far in as possible.

Thirdly, apply pressure.  If you can place a protective piece of wood to either side of the door and use G-clamps to hold them in place then the pressure will help the glue to stick.  Leave the clamps on for about 24 hours.  Pressure is more effective than heat.